# Link a foreign C library with Haskell

Tags: haskell, hyperlink, ffi, flags, bluez

The tutorials online that talk about Haskell's FFI all make simple examples with a locally defined C file which is then compiled and linked with the Haskell binary. How would I do something more substantial, say, link my Haskell binary with a Bluetooth library?

Imagine that I have BlueZ and the required developer libraries installed on my system. In C I would just pass the flag `-lbluetooth` to GCC and it would work as intended. Can I pass this flag to Haskell in my cabal file and expect my FFI imports to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have something like this in your cabal file:

```
library
  exposed-modules: YourBluetoothBinding
  build-depends:   {- Haskell dependencies -}
  c-sources:     {- your own C files that may be needed -}
  pkgconfig-depends: bluez
  includes: bluetooth/bluetooth.h
  extra-libraries: bluetooth
```

I'm not sure whether `pkgconfig-depends` does anything on Windows.

Comment: I have tried if this work yet, but given that it does, how did you know to include it like this? I'd like to learn how to do this for arbitrary C libraries.

Comment: I don't know if those particular bluetooth options are right. As for the Cabal fields – [their documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package.html?highlight=extra-libraries#pkg-field-extra-libraries) is unfortunately extremely meagre; I've learned about them basically just by looking how existing FFI packages on Hackage do it.

Comment: The ffmpeg-light bindings are amazingly good.  You can see [that cabal file](https://github.com/acowley/ffmpeg-light/blob/master/ffmpeg-light.cabal) uses pkgconfig-depends as shown above.  Writing the actual foreign function bindings can be done manually or you can use yet another language+tool such as c2hs or hsc2hs.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson the ffmpeg-light bindings are amazingly good and are good example of how to set up C dependencies with cabal; but I haven't had a 100% success rate getting it to compile. I can't remember what the error messages are but I think it's basically a version bounds issue.